# speed up perl hashes in foreach loop and better algorithm

Tags: perl, hash, foreach

I have 2 hashes ->  `%a` and `%b`.
Hash `%a` is from `temp.txt`

```
my %a = map{
  my $short = substr($_,12);
  $count++ => {$short => $_};
  } @a;

my %b = map {
   $_ => $_;
  } @b;

%a = (
    '1' =>  {'We go lunch' => 'We go lunch 9 pm'},
    '2' =>  {'We go break' => 'We go break 8 pm'},
    '3' =>  {'We go lunchy' => 'We go lunchy 8 pm'}
);

%b = (
    'We go lunch' => 'We go lunch',
    'We go break' => 'We go break',
    'We go lunchy' => 'We go lunchy'
);

foreach my $key (keys %a){
  foreach my $key2 (keys %{$a{$key}}){
      if(exists $b{$key2}){
      delete $a{$key}{$key2};
      delete $a{$key};
  }
  }
}

my @another;
foreach my $key ( sort {$a<=>$b} keys %a) {
   foreach my $key2 (keys %{$a{$key}}){
      $another[$count] = $a{$key}{$key2};
      $count++;
   }
}
```

how can I speed up this? is my hashes weird? It took 30 seconds to output `@another` through 25144 lines of words in `temp.txt`.

Is it necessary to make hash of hash for `%a`? 
The reason is I want any `%b{$key}` value in `%a` to be deleted.
I'm still learning Perl if you guys have any better way of doing this, very much appreciated, possibly using map and grep? and better algorithm?

**previous workaround**

if you see every @b is shorter string than every @a but still within @a. I had try to use

```
foreach (@b) { 
my $source = $_; 
@another = grep !(/$source/i), @a;}
```

but still it doesn't work. I was confused and thus came this hash of hash in %a and make hash %b from @b just to get rid of every instances value of @b in @a. which comes out as weird hash. lol

Comment: Why do you set %a twice?

Comment: the reason is under that "previous workaround"

Comment: Not it isn't. It says you're making %b from @b, but you're not. (Well, you do, but you complete erase all that work.)

Comment: hash %b is not being erased. I only delete hash %a

Answer (score 2):

There are a few unknowns here - how is `%b` built for example. 
Otherwise, a few observations:

You should use another array instead of `%a`:

```
  my @c = map{
    { "".substr($_,12) => $_}
   } @a;
```

If you already have `%b` defined, you could further optimize it by:

```
my @another = grep !exists $b{ substr($_,12) }, @a;
```

Hope this helps

Also, don't forget to **always** `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in the beginning of your program.

**Explanations:**

Your code puts everything in `%a`, traverse it and eliminates what shouldn't be there. 
I think you could simply `grep` and keep in an array only the desired results.

The optimized code should become:

```
use strict;
use warning;

my %b = (
    'We go lunch' => 'We go lunch',
    'We go break' => 'We go break',
    'We go lunch' => 'We go lunch'
);

#add code that initially fills @a

my @another = grep { !exists $b{ substr($_,12) } } @a;
```

Comment: I did this grep before this one but to no avail because @a is not character by character the same as @b (previous code) so everything is undef in @another.  maybe my example is not right. I changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are very confused. First of all, `substr $_, 12` returns all the characters *after* the twelfth in the string, and so doesn't create the data structure you say it does. Secondly, you are using hash of hashes `%a` as an *array of arrays*, as the keys are integers without gaps in the sequence, and the value you are storing is a simple string pair.

The biggest problem for us is that you don't explain your *goal* in all this.

What it looks like is that you want to end up with the array `@another` containing all the lines from `temp.txt` that don't begin with any of the strings in `@b`. Is that about right?

I would do it by building a regular expression from array `@b`, and checking each line from the file as I read it.

This program demonstrates. I have renamed array `@b` to `@exclude` as the former is a *terrible* name for a variable. The regular expression is built by preceding each element of the array with `^` to anchor the regex at the beginning of the string, and appending `\b` to force a word boundary (so that, for instance, `lunch` doesn't match `lunchy`). Then all the elements are joined together using the `|` alternation operator, resulting in a regex that matches a string that starts with *any* of the lines in `@exclude`.

After that it is a simple matter to read through the file, check each line against the regex, and push onto `@another` those lines that don't match.

Note that, as it stands, the program reads from the `DATA` file handle so that I could include some test data in the source. You should change it by uncommenting the `open` line, and deleting the line `my $fh = *DATA`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#open my $fh, '<', 'temp.txt' or die $!;
my $fh = *DATA;

my @exclude = (
  'We go lunch',
  'We go lunchy',
  'We go break',
);

my $exclude_re = join '|', map "^$_\\b", @exclude;

my @another;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  push @another, $line unless $line =~ $exclude_re;
}

print "$_\n" for @another;

__DATA__
We go breakfast 6 am
We go lunch 9 pm
We go break 8 pm
We go lunchy 8 pm
We go supper 7 pm
```

**output**

```
We go breakfast 6 am
We go supper 7 pm
```